How to run integration/component test from cmd with maven
I am trying to run integration tests from cmd MacOS using maven and the following command:
mvn test -Dspring.profiles.active=component-test -Dspring.config.location=classpath:/src/test/resources/application-component-test.properties -Dsurefire.failIfNoSpecifiedTests=false

However, I get that no tests are being run: Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0. The reason I am trying to do so is because of a previusly asked question about NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/xml/bind/JAXBException that no matter what I do, I cannot solve on my MacOS Intellij.

If you are trying to run integration tests, they don't run during the test phase; they will run during the verify phase.  However, you must also include the failsafe plugin to run your integration tests.
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

Ensure you include this plugin and run mvn verify; this should get you going.
